# Who is legally responsible for the traffic signage of a drive thru that intersects a sidewalk?

Tags: california, traffic

So here is the setup:

[image]

Drivers keep coming in through the oneway drive thru even though the "do no enter" sign is there. Although, to the credit of the people who do this, the sign is a bit high off the ground (second image). Who is legally responsible for this poor placement of traffic signage, and who do I talk to to have it changed?

To be clear, the offending maneuver in the first image is the arrow turning left.

Comment: Where is this located? Country? If U.S., State,  City?

Comment: OH! missed that